# UIImage rendering not clear on iPad Mini

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview, uiimage

The following code block is used in my application to take a screenshot of the current screen of an iPad mini(768 x 1024):

```
UIImage *img;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return img;
```

In a different viewcontroller, I present a UIScrollView with a width of 540 and a height of 290. I display the screencapture UIImage in a UIImageView which I create programmatically initWithFrame with a rectangle width of 250 and height of 250. The content size of the scrollview is 768 by 250.

Now running the application, I display four rectangles and screenshot the screen using the above block of code. Transitioning to the UIScrollView, the image is not clear (and by not clear, some rectangles are missing sides while some are thicker than others). Is there a way to display the image clearer? I know the image has to be scaled down from the original 768 by 1024 to 250 by 250. Could this be the problem? If so, what would be the best fix?

**Edit**:

[image: Screensheet]

Above a screenshot of the image I want to capture.

Below is the UIImage in UIImageView within a UIScrollView:

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing the clarity issue. Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: UI Elements can appear blurry when their frame property contains numbers that are not integers. Try casting the individual frame elements (specifically the origin) to `int`.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook What exactly do you mean? I have made an edit with images now.

Comment: Looks like this might be an effect of the built-in downscaling. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the [content mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) of your UIImageViews. If you use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, you shouldn't see any extra space around the edges.

**Update**: From the screenshots you posted, it looks like this is just an effect of the built-in downscaling in UIKit. Try manually downscaling the image to fit [using Core Graphics](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) first. Alternatively, you might want to use something like the [CILanczosScaleTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CILanczosScaleTransform) Core Image filter (iOS 6+).

Comment: Sorry but just to be clear, when you say manually downscale the image, what method are you suggesting would be best to accomplish this?

Comment: Here's one way to do it using Core Graphics: [Resize a UIImage the right way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

Answer (score 2):

Cast each coordinate to int, or use CGRectIntegral, to do that directly on a CGRect, decimal point requires AA and makes images blurry.